# Using OnTouchListener to implement a slider structure in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project which has a double slider structure in it.I am using The ontouchlistener to cause the sliding motion.There are two sliders ,one is the left slider and another is the right slider.The sliding gesture of the right slider all of a sudden stopped working.I havent made changes to the main class.When the right slider opens a webservice is called to populate a listview in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       public class Swipe_Activity extends Activity {
      LinearLayout swipe_layout;
         @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        swipe_layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_swipe);
        swipe_layout.setOnTouchListener( new OnSwipeTouchListener(this));
        }
       public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

       private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 60;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 60;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }  
                    result = true;
                } 
             /*   else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }*/
               //     result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Log.i("Post", "right");
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Log.i("Post", "left");
        Intent intent=new Intent(Swipe_Activity.this,Questions_Answers_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Log.i("Post", "Top");
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Log.i("Post", "Bottom");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


}
```

Comment: Still the same problem persists.The left slider works fine,but the right slider doesnt work.

Comment: Why does the left slider work fine,when i do onswiperight for the left slider it works fine.But when i press onswipeleft or onswiperight for the right slider the methods are not called.It was working fine till yesterday.Working against a deadline here.please help

Comment: private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 60;
 private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 60;

Comment: Should i post the code for the content in the right slider?

Comment: GestureListener this is a class which handles the swipes.you just give its instance in the onTouchListener on and view on which u want to implement swipe logic

Comment: Still the same issue, the left slider works the right slider doesnt.

Comment: is it possible that the code for the content of the rightslider is causing an issue?Should i post it here?

Comment: Thanks for helping.The issue was i changed the listview from match_parent to wrap_content and it works.WIERD!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like,

**In GestureListener**

```
@Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                             onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What is setpreviousmonth,setnextmonth and refreshcalender,in my case?

Comment: The code was working fine , it stopped working with the right slider all of a sudden.

Comment: Tried the above,still the right slider doesnt work :(